# How to give a model from qtreeview two clickable icons

Tags: c++, qt, qtreeview

my problem is i want to add a new function to the item in teeview but the method of `QAbstractItemModel::data(index,role)` only give one checkbox or one icon to set
now i want to set two picture,which is clickable.
can it use the method of 'paint' or others?

[image]

Comment: You should consider creation of separate column, that might be better UX solution and much simpler to implement. But if you really want two icons - QItemDelegate should help here.

Comment: @jdfa I tried the delegate way but i met some problem, like the item cannot pack up ,when the delegate is consisted of two push buttons , i will try the way to add column, thanks a lot.

Comment: @jdfa    It seems to satisfy my requirements but the columns don't lean to the right, there's no way to change them, and there's no way to get the events that click on the icon. The layout now looks like the image shows.